# How do you persist an object throughout an android application?

Tags: java, android

When the application loads I do a request to a webservice that returns JSON which is converted to Plain Old Java Objects:

Airports:

```
public class Airports {

    private List<Airport> airportList = new ArrayList<Airport>();

    ...get and set...
}
```

Airport:

```
public class Airport {
    private String id;
    private String airport;
    private String city;

    ...get and set...
}
```

Now because doing a request everytime is costly, I would like this list of Airports (the airports object) to be accessible throughout the application. How can I access the data of a single instance of this object.

Storing in SQLite would be overkill.

Now I have read about using the Application Subclass, Singleton classes and Shared Preferences.

I am not too sure which solution best fits the problem?

Comment: sqlite is made for storaing huge data, hence you could got for sqlite

Comment: It should persist as long as the application is loaded, or as long as it's installed?

Comment: Personally, I'd do it with a singleton.

Comment: I would write the JSON to a file and have my coffee and live my life :)

Answer (score 1):

Choosing one of the ways you have said is based on what behavior you would want about those data. If you would want stability of those data during application life cycle, using singleton or application subclass would be okay, but otherwise if you want those data to be persistent for ever until the app is installed, you probably need SQLite or file or Shared Preferences. So

**Persistent during app life-cycle**

- Java singleton pattern (generally using *static* members)
- Sub-classing of `Application` class

**Persistent until app is installed**

- SQLite (usually used for large amount of data)
- Shared preferences (usually for small data)
- File

Note that SQLite and shared preferences approach is more structured than using raw files.

Answer (score 1):

Store the json in shared preferences if it's not too big (few hundreds sizes in kb).

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("jsondata", jsonData.toString());
editor.commit();
```

Retrieval:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String stringJson = sharedPref.getString("jsondata");
if(stringJson != null){
  JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(stringJson);
}else{
  //retrieve from web services
}
```